# Find all asp.net usercontrols that are not being used / referenced

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a project with hundreds of usercontrols but many of them are old and no longer used. Is there are quick way to find out which ones can be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any VS function/tool that can do this but you can look for the following ways they are imported:

- Through the [Page.LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) call
- The @[Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c76dd5k1.aspx) page directive
- The [controls](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx) section of the web.config

If you knock together a script to run through all of your codebehinds, .aspx files and web.config files, you would be able to build up a list of all controls in use. Then delete the unused ones.